# Mysterious app crash after AppStore update

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, app-store

We have released an app to the AppStore and after an update it crashes after trying to login. We have been heavily relying on a `CoreData` database in it and we think it is the reason of the crash. Nevertheless I couldn't get any valuable info from the device, just a crash log that features some thread information. Here's how it looks:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32b3e5b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x337cbd18 -[NSError dealloc] + 56
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32b40484 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 164
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31bc843c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
4   Foundation                      0x337ccf76 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 118
5   CoreData                        0x32f6d4ae -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1206
6   ourapp                      0x0012fbf8 0xba000 + 482296
7   CoreData                        0x32f70bbe developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 86
8   CoreData                        0x32f70cee -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 90
9   ourapp                      0x0012fb4c 0xba000 + 482124
10  ourapp                      0x000c4e08 0xba000 + 44552
11  ourapp                      0x000cced4 0xba000 + 77524
12  ourapp                      0x000db50a 0xba000 + 136458
13  ourapp                      0x0014c41a 0xba000 + 599066
14  Foundation                      0x33893ef2 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 14
15  Foundation                      0x337d39ec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
16  Foundation                      0x337d3908 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
17  CFNetwork                       0x38da65dc ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 24
18  CFNetwork                       0x38da5cc8 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 52
19  CFNetwork                       0x38dce130 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 16
20  CoreFoundation                  0x31bcb74a CFArrayApplyFunction + 174
21  CFNetwork                       0x38dce58e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
22  CFNetwork                       0x38d3215a MultiplexerSource::perform() + 186
23  CoreFoundation                  0x31c5a680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
24  CoreFoundation                  0x31c59f7a __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 358
25  CoreFoundation                  0x31c58cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
26  CoreFoundation                  0x31bcbeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
27  CoreFoundation                  0x31bcbd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
28  GraphicsServices                0x399c92e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
29  UIKit                           0x394872f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
30  ourapp                      0x000be76a 0xba000 + 18282
31  ourapp                      0x000bb684 0xba000 + 5764
```

Are there any other chances I can get more info out of this situation? How can I plug it in to XCode and possibly trace the crash or it can only be done post-factum?

And most importantly, what do you think is causing the crash?

Comment: Did you debug in device with new changes ?

Comment: @Maulik that's the latest version of the app and it gives the crash

Comment: Start with the static analyser also enable NSZombie.

Comment: @Maulik which instrument should I use when debugging an app straight from the AppStore? I can't install an XCode version for now.

Comment: you need to run your code via xcode for analyser

Comment: @Maulik The thing is I can't launch it from Xcode because that would not simulate the real AppSotre conditions - I need the app to be updated from the AppStore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: Is there a migration involved from old version to new version?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist no, nothing should be done from the user, it all should be handled automatically. But it does not.

Comment: @SergiusGee: did you see the symbolication ?

Comment: @Maulik I can't get any crash reports from iTunes Connect right now, only the ones that are physically stored on the devices available at hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our problem was connected with Core Data lightweight migration. We were using the "Magical Record" library for handling our Core Data fetches and updating it solved the problem.

Also, [this blog post](http://pablin.org/2013/05/24/problems-with-core-data-migration-manager-and-journal-mode-wal) was quite useful.